# How can I make an image with a link change the link address when a certain action has happened?

Tags: javascript, button, soundcloud

I am trying to make a buy button that updates the link address when a user clicks on a song from the Soundcloud list. I'll figure out how to get the Soundcloud buy urls, but I was wondering was there a standard that does that link changing action? Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript it can be done as such:

```
var linkImage = document.getElementById('idOfImage');

linkImage.setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');
```

For the 'buy urls' use can use the output of the SoundCloud api, which provides a `purchase_url` link.

[SoundCloud API reference](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)

Register your application on SoundCloud to get an api key. 
Example in Jquery:

```
$.getJSON('api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=<SoundCloud Url>&client_id=xxx', function(data) {
   buy_url = data.purchase_url;
});
```

Comment: sounds good, and how would i implement the purchase_url? If not too extensive for you.